# using APITestCase with django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, rest, testing, django-rest-framework

I followed this code:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class AccountTests(APITestCase):
    def test_create_account(self):
        """
        Ensure we can create a new account object.
        """
        url = reverse('account-list')
        data = {'name': 'DabApps'}
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        self.assertEqual(response.data, data)
```

Found in the django-rest-framewok docs here:

[DRF API-guide: Testing example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#example)

I created a single `Model` with a single field `name`, and I am still getting a "bad request 400 error". The view and `reverse` name is also set up correctly, and I have manually tested viewing the URL with success. I don't have Authentication enabled

And can't figure out if I am missing a step?

Does anyone have a working example of a `django-rest-framework APITestCase create model object` test code snippet?

Comment: Have you tried printing `response.errors` or `response.data`?

Comment: @meshy, I ended up just following the git repo below to get it working. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This `GIT` repo has several working examples, which I was able to follow and get `APITestCase` working:

[django-rest-framework-oauth2-provider-example/apps/users/tests.py](https://github.com/erkarl/django-rest-framework-oauth2-provider-example/blob/master/apps/users/tests.py)

Answer (score 1):

It could be a JSON decode error.

In the line `self.client.post(url, data, format='json')` use `json.dumps(data)` and try.